# PHP shows up as plain text after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: apache2, php, 18.04

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. Now apache serves my website's php as plaintext php. I've already tried:
[Why are my PHP files showing as plain text? (on Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text) and [PHP 7 and apache displays plain text and cannot be restarted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780017/php-7-and-apache-displays-plain-text-and-cannot-be-restarted). The installed php packages are:

```
php              php7.2-cli       php7.2-fpm       php7.2-mbstring  php7.2-pgsql     php7.2-sqlite3   php7.2-zip       php-curl         php-igbinary     php-pgsql        php-xml
php7.2           php7.2-common    php7.2-gd        php7.2-mysql     php7.2-readline  php7.2-xml       php-bz2          php-fpm          php-mbstring     php-soap         php-xmlrpc
php7.2-bz2       php7.2-curl      php7.2-json      php7.2-opcache   php7.2-soap      php7.2-xmlrpc    php-common       php-gd           php-mysql        php-sqlite3      php-zip
```

One of the websites in question can be seen [here](https://www.bergenthal-foto.de/).

The apache `error.log`:

```
[Thu Apr 26 16:02:12.740886 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6504] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Thu Apr 26 16:02:13.001806 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7704] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Apr 26 16:02:13.001900 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7704] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And the `access.log`:

```
<MYIP> - - [26/Apr/2018:16:02:40 +0200] "-" 408 3435 "-" "-"

<MYIP> - - [26/Apr/2018:16:02:40 +0200] "-" 408 3435 "-" "-"

<MYIP> - - [26/Apr/2018:16:02:40 +0200] "-" 408 3435 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Probably you should install and enable the right Apache's php module `libapache2-mod-php7.2` (and purge the old one).

Comment: libapache2-mod-php7.2 is already the newest version. :(

Comment: Maybe you should enable it: `sudo a2enmod php7.2`.

Comment: Module php7.2 already enabled. ;)

Comment: Try to flush your browsers cache. This is the last idea that I have :)

Comment: well that simple solution did the trick. Thanks a lot for the new perspective :)

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Comment: Could you write the answer as an answer then please? It would be helpful if other people stumble upon the same situation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what got my installation sorted

```
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

Comment: Thanks, to me enabling php7.2 module worked perfectly,- seems there was conflicts between multiple versions of php

Comment: I only needed the second line a2enmod. Once that was enabled the application came up. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in addition to the commands in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028574/527764), you need

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
```

as well. Somehow it has disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be related to having 2 versions of PHP installed and enabled at the same time after the upgrade. Neither of the above worked for me, so I uninstalled Apache, PHP 7.1 and PHP 7.2, reinstalled Apache and PHP 7.2 and things are working now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS to 18.04 LTS using the `do-release-upgrade` tool. In my case the following helped:

`sudo apt-get install php7.2 libapache2-mod-php`

This added `libapache2-mod-php7.2` as well. `php7.2-common` and `php7.2-cli` were already installed, so they were ignored. `sudo a2enmod php7.2` was executed automatically by `apt-get`.

BTW, you can diagnose this problem by creating a file `/var/www/html/phpinfo.php`with the following contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and then pointing your browser to the URL `http://your.server/phpinfo.php`. You should get a nice webpage with all the PHP settings. If you get the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` text instead then you need to install the packages described above.

I am mentioning this because first I just ran `php -v` on the command line and it told me that PHP 7.2 was installed. Which is sort-of true (as the command-line stuff from the package `php7.2-cli` was indeed installed), but it's not the whole story. :-)